# How to select a function in an if statement

Tags: python, function, input

I need help with allowing the user to select a value and call a function accordingly.

```
weight = input('Enter K for kilos  or P for pounds : ')

unit = weight

if unit == "K":

    def metricTopound(kilograms):

        pounds = kilograms * 2.2
        ounces = pounds * 16

        return int(pounds), ounces % 16

        kilograms = float(input("How many Kilos ? "))
        lb, o = metricTopound(kilograms)
        print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. '\
        'This is {} pounds and {} ounces.'.format(kilograms, lb, o))

elif unit == " P ":

    def poundsToMetric(pounds):
        kilograms = pounds / 2.2
        grams = kilograms * 1000

        return int(kilograms), grams % 1000

        pounds = float(input("How many Pounds? "))
        kg, g = poundsToMetric(pounds)
        print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. '\
        'This is {} kilograms and {} grams.'.format(pounds, kg, g))
```

The user should be able to select `P` to get the weight in kilos or `K` to get the weight in pounds.

Comment: Why are you defining the function in `if-else` block? Define them outside and call them whenever condition is satisfied.

Comment: Why would your function `return()` before the function execution is completed?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to define the functions beforehand:

```
def metricTopound(kilograms):
    pounds = kilograms * 2.2
    ounces = pounds * 16

    return int(pounds), ounces % 16

def poundsToMetric(pounds):
    kilograms = pounds / 2.2
    grams = kilograms * 1000

    return int(kilograms), grams % 1000

weight = input('Enter K for kilos  or P for pounds : ')

unit = weight

if unit == "K":
    kilograms = float(input("How many Kilos ? "))
    lb, o = metricTopound(kilograms)
    print('The amount of kilograms you entered is {}. '\
    'This is {} pounds and {} ounces.'.format(kilograms, lb, o))
elif unit == "P":
    pounds = float(input("How many Pounds? "))
    kg, g = poundsToMetric(pounds)
    print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. '\
    'This is {} kilograms and {} grams.'.format(pounds, kg, g))
```

Comment: Thank You, I really appreciate your help. The script is now running

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not taking input in proper type and you should define above or in separate file and then **call** the function
2. Lines below `return` statement will never get executed
3. You are passing `" P "` to comparison so user need to add space then P and trailing space.

**Fixed code**

```
def metricTopound(kilograms):

        pounds = kilograms * 2.2
        ounces = pounds * 16

        return int(pounds), ounces % 16


def poundsToMetric(pounds):
        kilograms = pounds / 2.2
        grams = kilograms * 1000

        return int(kilograms), grams % 1000


unit = raw_input('Enter K for kilos  or P for pounds : ') #get as string

weight= input("Ener Weight") #get as integer

if unit == "K":
       metricTopound(weight)
       kilograms = float(input("How many Kilos ? "))
       lb, o = metricTopound(kilograms)
       print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. '\
       'This is {} pounds and {} ounces.'.format(kilograms, lb, o))



elif unit == "P":
         poundsToMetric(weight)
         pounds = float(input("How many Pounds? "))
         kg, g = poundsToMetric(pounds)
         print('The amount of pounds you entered is {}. '\
         'This is {} kilograms and {} grams.'.format(pounds, kg, g))
```